# Is it OK to remove this SaleTracker app?

Tags: system-apps, bloatware

I was going through apps I could uninstall and discovered [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KqB.png) app called "Launcher" which lives in `/system/app/SaleTracker.apk`. Googling for the APK name [suggests](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/malware/potentially-unwanted-application/android-saletrack-a/) this is some sort of malware (checking with MalwareBytes didn't seem to confirm this) and should be removed, but I'd like to have a second opinion before removing a system component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't any vital Android component, as I don't have it on my OnePlus One, so you *could* go ahead and either freeze or remove it and see after a restart if that poses a problem. If so, you should have a backup ready to put it back to its former place.